# How to Find Recent or Today’s Modified Files in Linux

Tags: linux, file, date, unix, timestamp

I have a requirement that will have to find out latest modified files list along with date and time.
mainly we have **2 files that boot.properties and ldap related files** as part of beadmin password change activity.

```
find /target_directory -type f -name "*boot.properties" -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

is giving only boot.properties but I need to find other files which is in different location.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this if you have different location and file names.

```
find /root_directory \
\( \( \
 -path "/target_directory1/*" -type f  -name "*boot.properties" \) -o \( \
 -path "/target_directory2/*" -type f  -name "*boot2.properties" \
 \) \) -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

also, you have other options to find by modified date too.
check this article 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-osxfind-files-by-date/

Answer (score 0):

`find` supports multiple path arguments, so you could do something like

```
find /target_dir /other -type f \( -name "*boot.properties" -o -name "other*" \) -exec ls -ltr {} +
```